# trying to write nested JSON into File

Tags: java, android, json, file, stack-overflow

It's my first post here.

Well, I got a problem trying to write nested JSON into File in Android. 
It show me a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

My question is: Is there any way to write a nested JSON into file without having any kind of problem with stack.

I'll show you nested JSON and the way I'm trying to write into the File

```
    JSONObject fingerPrint = new JSONObject();

    try {
        fingerPrint.put("fingerPrint", fingerPrint);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Error parsing creating JSON \"fingerPrint\"");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject fingerPrintMaterial = new JSONObject();

    try {
        fingerPrintMaterial.put("methodType", FingerprintFacade.MAC_SHA256);
        fingerPrintMaterial.put("keySize", 5);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Error parsing creating JSON \"fingerPrintMaterial\"");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject userFingerPrint = new JSONObject();

    try {
        userFingerPrint.put("fingerPrint",  fingerPrint);
        userFingerPrint.put("fingerPrintMaterial", fingerPrintMaterial);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now this is the way I'm trying to write:

```
    try {
        BufferedWriter file=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToNonEncryptedTxt+filename, true));
        //FileWriter file = new FileWriter(pathToNonEncryptedTxt+filename);
        file.write(userDigitalContent.toString(2));
        file.newLine();
        file.write(userFingerPrint.toString(2));
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Error saving JSON into "+filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Error saving JSON into "+filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Oh!! BTW, I need to output something like that into a .txt File:

```
    {
    "userFingerPrint": {
            "fingerPrint": {
                "fingerPrint": "fingerPrintValue"
            },
            "fingerPrintMaterial": {
                 "methodType": "methodTypeValue",
                 "keySize": "5"
            }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: can you please put which type of output you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is some thing wrong in creating `JSONObject` in your code. Refer this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) for creating `JSONObject` once you create `JSONObject` you can get Sting from `JSONObject` by calling `jsonObj.toString(`) and write that string to file

Comment: Actually I've followed that tutorial and I think there is nothing wrong creating JSON. Anyway that tutorial use a simple JSON (with a JSONArray) but not a nested one as I'm using in my code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: at what point you getting exception, try to print JSONObject and check if its creating properly

Comment: what you doing at this point, U trying to put same object inside the same obj.

try {
        fingerPrint.put("fingerPrint", fingerPrint);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Error parsing creating JSON \"fingerPrint\"");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: WOw...thanks at all...You've solved my problem. I know that was a ridiculous problem but it was messing with me for couple of days...Thanks to all!!

Comment: accept this as answer pls if it had solved ur problem

Comment: Done!, Sorry but it's my first time here. Thanks